How do I correctly import a node module (supabase) into a supabase client in a Vite React chrome extension? It causes service-worker to be inactive
I'm writing a google chrome extension in Vite and React that uses a service_worker which imports a supabase_client that I wrote. The supabase client is trying to import createClient from @supabase/supabase-js".
The import in supabase_client.js is causing an error when refreshing the extension in Google Chrome and makes the service worker inactive:
Service worker registration failed. Status code: 3
An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.
My project structure is as follows:
-- node_modules
   --@supabase
-- public
    --- manifest.json
   |__background
      ---service_worker.js
   |__src
      ---supabase_client.js
--index.html

The files are:
service_worker.js:
import supabase from "../src/supabase_client.js";
...


supabase_client.js
import { createClient } from "../../node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js"; // This causes the issue

const supabaseUrl = "example";
const supabaseKey = "example";

const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey);


export default supabase;

manifest.json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "name",
    "description": "description",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "permissions": ["background", "tabs", "scripting", "webRequest", "activeTab", "storage"],
    "host_permissions": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "icons": {
        "32": "images/icon.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background/service-worker.js",
        "type": "module"
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version": "92"
}

I've tried changing the import statement to:

/../node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js
/node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js
@supabase/supabase-js

but it doesn't work.
I'm wondering if it's an issue that the service-worker.js and supabase-client.js are in public, and don't have access to node modules? If so, where should they be? I couldn't get the manifest.json to find the service-worker if it wasn't in public.
Would appreciate any help to get this to build properly.

It probably uses XMLHttpRequest or another DOM feature, either way it's not compatible with service workers, which is what code 3 means. You can use it in the offscreen document or just call fetch() explicitly.
